# How to save Omelette from breaking while keeping the oil quantity low?

Tags: omelette

When I make Omelette in normal pan (not non-stick), it breaks and then I have to make Egg bhurji instead. I did made successfully fully intact Omelette but for that I have to increase oil quantity, which is not a good idea.

So how I can save my Omelette from breaking while cooking. I only add egg, green chilies, pinch of salt and onion and use soybean or sunflower oil.

Comment: Have you tried using a non-stick pan? I ask because in your question you specify that you're using *not non-stick*, and I personally find it absolutely impossible to make eggs of any kind in a not non-stick pan without leaving half the eggs in it when I'm done.  I usually make an omelette in a non-stick pan with a little butter using the lift-and-drip method and medium to high heat (some people like low heat, but that's another question).  Nothing sticks and the finished omelette slides right out onto a plate.

Comment: @senschen yes and it worked quite fine on non stick pan.

Comment: Then why not just use the non-stick pan?  That's almost always going to be the best solution for eggs.

Comment: @senschen or use a little more oil/butter. I mean... we have ways to deal with exactly this problem, OP just doesn't want to use them.

Comment: @SnakeDoc Maybe its just me, but it doesn't matter how much fat I use, if the pan isn't non-stick, my eggs are going to be ruined.  OP asked how to not break the omelette without adding more fat, he never said "and without a non-stick pan."  So that's why I suggested it.  Especially because if he's got one, that would be the solution I'd go for. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't necessarily have to increase oil quantity, you have to reduce friction. There are a few variables to consider:

- Tools - What type of spatula are you using? If it is a thin spatula, I have found that this increases the likelihood of breakage. I prefer one of two methods;

  1. use a wide rubber spatula or
  2. Use a fish spatula
- Method - There are numerous methods of omelet making out there. Some chefs, myself **not** included, add the egg mixture to the heated, oiled pan and then whisk the product to speed cooking time. While I understand the allure of this method, I don't prefer it. Personally, I use what I call the "lift and drip" method whereby I use the spatula to slide the omelet away from the side of the pan, lift the pan toward that side, and allow the egg mix to drip into the void created. It makes a slightly thicker omelet, which reduces the likelihood of tearing.

There are other variables that may come into play, as well, but I don't want to divert too far from your question. So, that being said, my personal method is:

1. Heat pan to just over medium heat, approximately 105 C (220 F)
2. Add lubricant (Personally, I use vegetable oil because it's cheap, but I keep it in a spray bottle for better coverage and less pooling)
3. Allow the egg mix to sit unfettered for forty seconds, or so
4. I use the lift and drip method mentioned above until the omelet is about 70% cooked
5. I add any other ingredients (chilies and onions since the salt should be mixed into the egg already)
6. Then I finish the omelet under the broiler/salamander until 95% done
7. Remove from heat, plate by sliding one side out and using the pan + gravity to fold, and serve

Be advised that this is indeed for an American bi-fold omelet, not a French tri-fold.